# ¿Cómo activar un botón al desplazarse al final de un PDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, .net, scroll

Necesito que al desplazarme al final del PDF se active el botón.

Tengo una ventana emergente en la cual se incrusta un PDF y un botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código HTML:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="hDocumento_id" />
        <input id="hUsuario" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
        <dx:ASPxCallback ID="CQFUNCIONES" ClientInstanceName="CQFUNCIONES" runat="server" >
            <ClientSideEvents  CallbackComplete ="function(s, e){Redireccionar(e.result);}" />
        </dx:ASPxCallback>
        <div class="wraper-popup">
            <div class="popup-body">
                <div class="innerPopup">
                    <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="iframeAbsolute" runat="server" src="" frameborder="0"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" typeof="application/pdf" ></iframe>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div><asp:Label ID="lblResultado" runat="server" ForeColor ="Red" Text="* Este documento se ha aceptado correctamente. Por favor, espere a que el sistema pueda gestionar la firma del documento. "></asp:Label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

       <%-- <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="cbViewer" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="callbackPanel">
            <PanelCollection>
                <dx:PanelContent runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                   <uc:PdfViewer ID="viewer" runat="server" PdfFilePath="FallCatalog.pdf" />
                </dx:PanelContent>
            </PanelCollection>
        </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>--%>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnFirmar" ClientInstanceName="btnFirmar" runat="server" Theme="MaterialCompact" Text="Aceptar" ClientEnabled="true" AutoPostBack="false">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){ verificarRespuestas();}" />
        </dx:ASPxButton> 
    </form>
```

**Código JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function verificarRespuestas() {
            CQFUNCIONES.PerformCallback(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value);
        }

        function Redireccionar(value) {
            var resultado = value;
            if (resultado == 1) {
                //window.parent.abreCuestionario(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value);
                mostrarConfirmarCorreo();
            } else {
                mostrarConfirmarCorreo();

                //window.parent.enviar_post(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value);
            }
        }

        function mostrarConfirmarCorreo() {
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Confirmar e-mail',
                message: function (dialog) {
                    var $content = $('<div><h5>Por favor, indique su correo electrónico.</h5><input type="email" name="direccionemail" id="direccionemail" class="form-control"><h5>Confirme su correo electrónico.</h5><input type="email" name="direccionemailConfirma" id="direccionemailConfirma" class="form-control"></div>');
                    return $content;
                },
                closable: false,

                buttons: [{
                    label: 'Cancelar',
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        dialog.close();
                        window.parent.cerrar_cuestionario();
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Aceptar',
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        var $mail = $('#direccionemail').val();
                        var $mailConfir = $('#direccionemailConfirma').val();

                        if (typeof $mail == "undefined" || $mail == "" || $mail == null) {
                            window.top.mostrarModal('Atención!', 'Introduzca una dirección de correo');
                        } else {
                            if ($mail !== $mailConfir) {
                                window.top.mostrarModal('Atención!', 'La direcciones de correo no coinciden');
                            } else {
                                window.parent.enviar_post(document.getElementById('hDocumento_id').value, $mail);
                                dialog.close();
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }]
            });
        }

        //$(function () {

        //    $(".innerPopup").mCustomScrollbar({
        //        axis: "y",
        //        scrollButtons: { enable: true },
        //        theme: "rounded-dots-dark",
        //        scrollInertia: '20',
        //        advanced: { autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true },
        //        callbacks: {
        //            onTotalScroll: function () {
        //                btnFirmar.SetEnabled(true);
        //            }
        //        }
        //    });

        //    var $vpH = $(window.top).height();
        //    $('.iframeAbsolute').height($vpH);
        //})
    </script>
```

Yo he realizado la activación y desactivación de los botones con formularios, pero nunca tras hacer scroll. Necesitaría hacerlo con Javascript o JQuery.

Quería hacer como en el ejemplo que ponen aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008823/enable-button-when-scroll-bootstrap-modal-to-bottom, pero intento poner el **disabled** y no me funciona, intento cambiarlo por el **enabled="true" o enabled="false"** y tampoco.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si estas usando controles de DevExpress deberías de ponerlo en los tags. Ya que al ser controles de servidor que generan scripts y HTML no podemos ver el resultado final para ayudarte.

Comment: Yo es que de ASPx no controlo nada ya que soy desarrollador front, esta ventana me la han pasado en el trabajo para que haga la funcionalidad que os comento y como acabo de poner, he visto un ejemplo en la versión en inglés de Stackoverflow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008823/enable-button-when-scroll-bootstrap-modal-to-bottom] y he estado poniendo disabled o enabled y me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: En ese caso te recomiendo hacer un viewSource de la página para ver  el html/scripts que genera. Como desarrollador Front necesitas el resultado "Final" del render de la página, no los controles de servidor. Una vez te funcione con el HTML resultante del final  transmitele esos camabios a los programadores del backend para que intenten adaptarlo.

Comment: Ok, intentaré hacerlo como me comentas y se lo diré a la gente de Back. Muchas gracias

Comment: He intentado poner el código HTML que me sale  cuando inspecciono el código del botón y al ponerlo para ver si funciona, me da un error, ya que al parecer hay más funcionalidad metida en el código ASPx del botón que ya me falla al intentar cargar la ventana porque al parecer le falta la llamada a un componente o algo de ASPx y yo de ese tipo de errores no controlo

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Yo no lo pude solucionar, se lo pasé a un compañero y creo que él lo pudo hacer. Muchas gracias